# Android studio keeps remaking modules and folders I deleted

Tags: android, android-studio

so im using Android Studio 2.1.3 (windows 10). And if i delete a module in Android studio (right click-> delete OR I go to module settings and press minus button). When i reopen android studio the folder is still there! It is of course empty, but it keeps appearing and I have no idea how to remove it.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

Since what you are doing only removes the Module from Android Studio, you have to physically delete the files from the file system. Here is an explanation:

http://esausilva.com/2014/08/28/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio/

Comment: @TheQ Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out. You have to go to settings.gradle and remove all your modules that you're not using.

Comment: I did that also, but Android Stuido keeps nagging me about module not compatible. I dont know where it is stored. I have searched everywhere for the name of the module, but can't find anything.